# How can I develop a model that detects organization names in an unstructured text

Tags: python, parsing, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am creating a resume parser algorithm in Python to extract experiences in a resume in pdf format. I am trying to detect organization names for each experience.

I have tried default spaCy NER model and most popular NER models on the huggingface. Problem here I think is since the text is in a unstructured format like:

```
Silver Technologies Ltd. Singapore Software Developer May 2008 – May 2009
```

This model can't parse and tag the text. I am trying to extract `Silver Technologies Ltd.` from this text. Other parts of the parser are using a rule based algorithm so I can use a rule based algorithm for organization detection. But I can't think of a rule that works on most of the examples. I would appreciate any suggestions that uses a model or a rule based algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use the spacy `en_core_web_trf model`. It will classify most occurances of organisation names as ORG.

Details about how to download and use the model is shown in the spacy tutorial link here: https://spacy.io/models

Please choose Accuracy option under `Select for`.

You can also check the output of given example against the same model hosted on hugging face following the link:
https://huggingface.co/spacy/en_core_web_trf?text=Silver+Technologies+Ltd.+Singapore+Software+Developer+May+2008+%E2%80%93+May+2009

The model is able to identify the text `Silver Technologies Ltd.` as an ORG.
as shown in the screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

A few options come to mind if you know data will always be in this order (organization, city, title, dates).  Nothing will be 100% but a combination of rules may get you close enough :

- look for organization tags like Ltd, Inc, Corp, etc. and take everything up to and including that point.
- look for city names and take everything before that point.  requires a list of cities, which could be rather large or not, depending on your memory needs and geographical range.  should be able to download a list of every city from country data available online (I imagine).  Maybe start with postcode data to get a list of all cities.
- look for a period, semicolon, dash, or some other indicator marking end of company name and beginning of city name.

If you don't know the order or number of items on the line (eg org name could be first, second, ...) then you can discard what you think/know are not org names and keep the rest.  For instance, it's easy to recognize and discard years and month names.  Cities as well, just need a complete list.

Position titles are trickier, they have a lot more variation.  Standard ones like Software Developer, Software Engineer are easy to spot, as are modifiers like Junior Developer, Senior Developer, etc.  It depends how broad your source data is.  If resumes are all software-related, it's easier to list them.  If resumes cover many different fields and types of positions, it becomes harder.  Perhaps develop a corpus of known job titles by scanning job posting sites, then pick out and discard any you find in a resume.  You'll have some false positives though - orgs like Software Developer Collective may get discarded.

Having done text-parsing tasks from pdf before, your best bet is to test and iterate.  Pick some rules to start, then make a list of matches and rejections.  Review the matches to make sure it captured the right things.  Review the rejections to see what you missed.  Then adjust your rules and run again.  It takes many iterations to suss out all the real-world variations you're not expecting.  People do strange things with text.

Also beware that what appears as a single line in a pdf may be broken into multiple lines in the text output from pdf libraries.  I ran into this problem before when parsing pdfs with python.